# How do i add this variable to my php submit code please

Tags: php, variables

when someone makes a payment (using stripe) I get notified by email - so all is well.

I get their email and the course (product) that they have bought but I am missing their name as written on their card - so - all i need to understand is how to insert the $name variable...

+++

```
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
email = $_POST['email'];
$fee = $_POST['fee'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
```

The above pulls the data and then the below formats it into an email - but the $name is missing and that is my question - how do I add that?

```
$to      = $alert_email;
$subject = 'Purchase by '.$email .' | '.$course;
$message = $email. ' purchased '.$course.' for $'.$fee.'.00';  
$headers = 'From: sales@ .com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: sales@ .com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So the line that needs $name is the $message line - do you add a period BEFORE the $name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it however you want with $message before it is passed to the mail function - why didn't you just try it and see?

Comment: Yes I would be it is a live script and people are taking payment - i dont want to risk it until I am sure! Thanks

Comment: You can always just roll up a test script that sends out an identical email straight to you, and then move that code over.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want $name to appear. In PHP . is the concatenation string, depending on where you want it you would need to add the . accordingly, (look at how $course is formatted)

Comment: thanks - so to get "Name of Person" + "Email of Person" 'that purchased' 'course' - 

Would I do this:

$message = $name ' with ' .$email. ' purchased '.$course.' for $'.$fee.'.00';  

thanks

Comment: close but you forgot one . :

$name.' with ' .$email. ' purchased '.$course.' for $'.$fee.'.00';

Answer (score 0):

The period is the concatenation operator in PHP.  So, if you wanted something like:

```
Bob Brown bbrown@example.com purchased...
```

You would code:

```
$message = $name. ' '. $email. ' purchased '.$course.' for $'.$fee.'.00';
```

You probably also want to do some checking to be sure the $_POST variables contain data.